# checkValidity() not working within function

Tags: javascript, html

I've got a simple function that does basically nothing but alert me of the validity:

```
function alertV(elem) {
    alert("here");
    alert(elem.checkValidity());
    alert("really");
}
```

The code for hooking this up:

```
var elements = document.forms["form"].getElementsByTagName("input");
for (i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    elements[i].onkeyup = function () { alertV(elements[i]) };
}
```

`Here` shows up fine, but `checkValidity()` isn't doing anything and is even causing the `really` call to be ignored. Am I passing in the arguments wrong? I essentially just want this, which works:

`<input type="text" onkeyup="alertV(this);">`

Comment: What do you see in the error console?

Comment: `i` is not what you think it is; you have the infamous block scope issue.  http://stackoverflow.com/q/750486/34397

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a closure:

```
elements[i].onkeyup = (function (a)
{
    return function ()
    {
        alertV(elements[a])
    }
})(i);
```

Comment: Edited because [IIFEs](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/) need to be wrapped in parentheses.

Comment: They are mandatory, at least in some JS engines (and possibly all of them). JS requires the parentheses in order to interpret a function declaration as an expression. Tested just now in the Chrome JS console with `function(i){console.log(i);}('test');` and `(function(i){console.log(i);})('test');`

Comment: @JustinMorgan there is a difference between declaration and expression.

Comment: That was originally my point; when the IIFE is the entire statement, the parentheses are what tell JS to interpret it as an expression, not a declaration. BUT...I've tested it again, and you're right: `var k = function(i){return i;}('test');` does work. I guess the assignment operator is a hint that what follows is an expression. My mistake, sorry about that.